# How to detect, if iewebgl is installed or not?

Tags: javascript, webgl

Is it possible to detect if iewebgl is installed or not?
I saw somewhere this, but this doesn't work:

```
var has_iewebgl = WebGLRenderingContext.hasOwnProperty('iewebgl')
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to detect webgl support in your browser is using [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com), a popular feature detection script. You can easily do it like so:

```
if (Modernizr.webgl){
       loadAllWebGLScripts(); // webgl assets can easily be > 300k
    } else {
      var msg = 'With a different browser you’ll get to see the WebGL experience here:    \
                 get.webgl.org.';
      document.getElementById( '#notice' ).innerHTML = msg;
    }
```

the full documentation is here [Modernizr Docs](http://modernizr.com/docs/)

I hope this answer helps you

Answer (score -1):

In your case, WebGLRenderingContext is probably undefined if iewebgl hasn't been installed.

Try

```
var has_iewebgl = (typeof WebGLRenderingContext != 'undefined') && WebGLRenderingContext.hasOwnProperty('iewebgl');
```